# Render 1 pixel from a 3D array in a HTML5 Canvas using putImageData() and an UInt8ClampedArray

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, array-push, putimagedata, uint8array

I tried my best to render just 1 pixel form a 3D Array in a HTML5 Canvas unsuccessfully.

(I know this has been done before but not with a 3D Array). But converting a 3D array to an Uint8ClampedArray and pushing to an Uint8ClampedArray isn't easy.

HTML5 also doesn't have another way to display a pixel manipulatable image.

Is it correct that putImageData() is for rendering vertical strings of pixels?

Here is my code, the problem is marked with: "WHAT DO I GOTTA DO HERE":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" + dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
      Index.html
    </title>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <canvas id="canvas">
    </canvas>
    <script>
      let a = new Array();
      a.push([]);
      a[x.length - 1].push([]);
      a[x.length - 1][a[a.length - 1].length - 1].push(0);
      a[x.length - 1][a[a.length - 1].length - 1].push(0);
      a[x.length - 1][a[a.length - 1].length - 1].push(0);
      a[x.length - 1][a[a.length - 1].length - 1].push(255);
      document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d").putImageData(new 
      ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray("WHAT DO I GOTTA DO HERE"), 1, 1), 1, 
      1);
    </script>
  </body>    
</html>
```

To test it you can use:

```
console.log(a);
console.log(a[0]);
console.log(a[0][0]);
console.log(a[0][0][0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a normal Javascript array - you just need to convert it to a clamped array. Off the top of my head, something like:

```
document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d").putImageData(new 
  ImageData(Uint8ClampedArray.from(x), 1, 1), 1, 1);
```

(or write your data into a new Uint8ClampedArray instead)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will check it out immediately! Oh no, it gives this error again: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'ImageData': The input data length is not equal to (4 * width * height) -, I'll try to take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you very much! You really helped me out! It seems to work when I do it like this:
    ImageData(Uint8ClampedArray.from(
    [
      x[0][0][0],
      x[0][0][1],
      x[0][0][2],
      x[0][0][3],
    ]
    ), 1, 1), 1, 1);

This is because I made a sepperate dimension for the RGBA values.

Answer (score 1):

Draw 200 x 200 red block into canvas. Requires `<canvas></canvas>`

I would advise against using a 3D array as it seems unnecessarily complicated

```
const width = 200;
const height = 200;

const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
const destData = new ImageData(width, height);
const dData = destData.data;

for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    const o = 4 * (y * width + x);
    dData[o] = 255; // R
    dData[o + 1] = 0; // G
    dData[o + 2] = 0; // B
    dData[o + 3] = 255; // A
  }
}

context.putImageData(destData, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I already have done the initializing with a while(x.length < canvas.width){x.push([])while(x[x.length] < canvas.height){x[x.length].push([])}}. I will also edit the variable names to something more logic.

Comment: Thank you for your advise but adapting to do every variable times 4 only in width is just not easy to handle for my human brain. Imagine a monitor that's 800 pixel wide but only 200 pixels high. Imagine if monitors had not only rgb but also yellow, cyan and violet.

Comment: Oh now I get it, you can just put the array variables in new ImageData().data[], thank you, you've been really helpful to me!

Comment: So am I getting it right that putImageData is for rendering a vertical string of pixels (and eventually multiple)?

Comment: `putImageData` draws what you've done onto the canvas at the end

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution and it works, I wanted to post to contribute to the community of Stack Overflow, so the next one with this question could easily do it there selves.

Just Like above it's a simplified version though:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" + dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
      Google Chrome, I suppose
    </title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: black; margin: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <canvas style="image-rendering: pixelated" id="canvas">
    </canvas>
    <script>
      var t =
      [
        240,
        128
      ];
      document.getElementById('canvas').width = t[0];
      document.getElementById('canvas').height = t[1];
      var a = new Array()
      {
        a.push([]);
        a[a.length - 1].push([]);
        a[a.length - 1][a[a.length - 1].length - 1].push(127, 127, 127, 255);
      }
      var i = 0;
      document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d').putImageData(new ImageData(Uint8ClampedArray.from
      (
        [].concat.apply
        ([],
          a[i]
        )
      ), 1), i, 0);
      i = i + 1;
      i = 0;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

as you can see, I've replaced variable x with a.

I hope this can help others also and thank you all for your suggestion!